# NodeJS Caching issue

Tags: node.js, caching, express, configuration

I am aware that Nodejs caches `required` files.

I have created a `sites` directory for the sole purpose of storing configuration files. I want to grab a dynamically named configuration file.

```
router.get('/:site?', function(req, res, next) {

    var site = (req.params && req.params.site) || 'default';

    var env = process.env.NODE_ENV,
        vaildEnv = ['development', 'staging', 'production'];

    if(vaildEnv.indexOf(env) === -1) env = 'default';

    var curDir = __dirname,
        siteDefaultConfigPath = curDir + '/../sites/' + env + '/default.js',
        siteConfigPath = curDir + '/../sites/' + env + '/' + site + '.js',
        siteDefaultConfig, siteConfig;

    if(!fs.existsSync(siteConfigPath)) return next();

    siteConfig = require(siteConfigPath);

    if(site !== 'default') {
        if(fs.existsSync(siteDefaultConfigPath)) {
            siteDefaultConfig = require(siteDefaultConfigPath);
            siteConfig = _.extend(siteDefaultConfig, siteConfig);
        }
    }
}
```

Now if I try to access http://website.com/ then it correctly fetches the default.js file. If I try accessing http://website.com/test then again it correctly fetches test.js file. But now if I try access http://website.com/ again then it still shows the test.js file! Not sure what is happening here. I even tried to `console.log(siteConfigPath)` and it shows the path to the correct file every time.

More interestingly, if I visit http://website.com/test and then and other URL like http://website.com/testing it always returns the correct file. It's only the http://website.com/ URL that shows the cached results.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is this:

```
siteDefaultConfig = require(siteDefaultConfigPath);
siteConfig = _.extend(_.clone(siteDefaultConfig), siteConfig);
```

You are permanently extending the object returned from require(siteDefaultConfigPath), so on subsequent requests, that object will no longer be the original object, but will instead return the extended version.

You need to clone the object returned from require(). You have a few alternatives, if it is a shallow object (no nested objects) you can use underscore's clone method:

```
siteDefaultConfig = _.clone(require(siteDefaultConfigPath))
```

However if you do have nested objects, you can try this approach:

```
siteDefaultConfig = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(require(siteDefaultConfigPath)))
```

Comment: Thanks! Can you throw some light on why the object gets extended 'permanently'?

Comment: It's just part of how Node.js works, and is actually a very important feature.   Keep in mind, that when you're programming a Node application, you're programming a server, not just a routine that would be executed in its own thread. Caching modules allows you to store application components in memory for subsequent requests, which is key for things like database connections. You can read more about it here http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_caching